# Grouped Select using 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've the following models

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zones
  attr_accessible :name
end

class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :cities
  attr_accessible :name
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zone
  attr_accessible :name, :zip_code
end
```

I'm actually displaying all cities seamless in the same select, but since now locations number is growing I'd like to display a grouped select using the location name as label and then display the alphabetically ordered options (cities :id, :name) for that location.

What I currently do to get the cities is `for each location get all zones, for each zone get all cities`, then I push them togheter in an instance variable and display them.
I've tried using grouped_collection_select but I can't figure out how could I use it in this case, I've also tried using grouped_options_for_select but I think the first one is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@cities= City.joins(:zone).where(:zones => { :location_id => @location.id })
```